# How to resample a pandas dataframe backwards

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

Hi I am trying to resample a pandas DataFrame backwards.
This is my dataframe:

```
seconds     = np.arange(20, 700, 60)
timedeltas  = pd.to_timedelta(seconds, unit='s')
vals        = np.array([randint(-10,10) for a in range(len(seconds))])
df  = pd.DataFrame({'values': vals}, index = timedeltas)
```

then I have

```
In [252]: df
Out[252]: 
          values
00:00:20       8
00:01:20       4
00:02:20       5
00:03:20       9
00:04:20       7
00:05:20       5
00:06:20       5
00:07:20      -6
00:08:20      -3
00:09:20      -5
00:10:20      -5
00:11:20     -10
```

and

```
In [253]: df.resample('5min').mean()
Out[253]: 
          values
00:00:20     6.6
00:05:20    -0.8
00:10:20    -7.5
```

and what I would like is something like

```
Out[***]: 
          values
00:01:20    6
00:06:20    valb
00:11:20    -5.8
```

where the values of each new time are the ones if I roll back the dataframe and compute the mean in each bin going from backwards to forward. For example in this 
case the last value should be

```
valc = (-6-3-5-5-10)/5.
valc= -5.8
```

which is the average of the last 5 values, and the first one should be the average of the only 2 first values because the "bin" is incomplete.

Reading pandas documentation I thought that I have to use the parameters *how='last'* but in my current version of pandas this is not working (version 0.20.3). Additionally I tried with the options *closed* and *convention*, but I wasn't able to perform this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: one simple way comes to me is to reorder it.Because the calculation usually goes row by row, however you want to start from the last row.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to sort the index in reverse order, then resample to get the desired results:

```
df.sort_index(ascending=False).resample('5min').mean()
```

[Resample reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) - When the resample starts the first bin is of max available length, in this case 5. Closed, label, convention parameters are helpful but do not compute the mean going from backwards to forward. To do that use sort.